# Linq Entity Framework select distinct with aggregate columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Say I have a `usertable` and an `ordertable`.

The criteria for the `usertable` is such that I will get the same user more than once.

How do I do a `distinct` and a `sum()` in Linq?

In SQL it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    u.Name, u.Phone, SUM(o.Amount)
FROM 
    User u
JOIN 
    Order o ON u.UserId = o.UserId
WHERE 
    u.Type = 1 OR u.External = 1
GROUP BY 
    Name, Phone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a query that sums the order amount for each user:

```
var query = users
  .Where(user => user.Type == 1 && user.External == 1)
  .GroupJoin(
    orders,
    user => user.Id,
    order => order.UserId,
    (user, ordersForUser) => new {
      user.Name,
      user.Phone,
      Amount = ordersForUser.Sum(order => order.Amount)
    }
  );
```

Your suggested query groups on user name and phone. This query groups on user ID which I assume is what you really want. There will be a difference if two distinct users have the same name and phone.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for my question above.

The problem now, is that I oversimplified my problem a little bit...
The relation isn't a direct parent/child.

The real tables are as follows:
    User <-- UserInvoice --> Products

Where "UserInvoice" is a many-to-many relation between User and Products

I need distinct User, with a sum from UserInvoice and a sum from Product, with a filter on UserInvoice and on user.

Answer (score 0):

For an example. Try out with your criteria. In example Count will give sum of the column with distinct.

```
  from l in logins
  group l by l.Date into g
  select new
 {
  Date = g.Key,
  Count = (from l in g select l.Login).Distinct().Count() 
 };
```